# How to show item from model as link in view

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a couple of fields being displayed in a view as such:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    string selectedRow = "success";
    if (item.ClientId == ViewBag.ClientId)
    {
        selectedRow = "success";
    }
    <tr class="@selectedRow">
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Purchases)
        </td>
      </tr>
```

I would like to display the each Purchases field as a link to redirect to another page with information related to it. Much similar to

```
@Html.ActionLink("Purchases", "Purchase", new {id = item.ClientId})
```

But I don't know how to properly reference each item.Purchases in Action Link.

Comment: your question is not clear, at all. We don't know what is the structure of Purchases, how many links you want to display, etc... You need to give more info (add a screenshot to clarify your desired outcome) so people can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering `Purchases` as a controller and `Purchase` as its action, you can use :

```
@if (item.Purchases != null)
{
    @Html.ActionLink(Convert.ToString(item.Purchases),"Purchase","Purchases", new {id = item.ClientId})
}
```

the above will do the trick.

**OR**

```
@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(item.Purchases)))
{ 
    <a href='@Url.Content("~/Purchases/Purchase?id=" + item.ClientId)'>item.Purchases</a>
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I need is to associate an action link to each text item of the model, something like this: @Html.ActionLink(**item.Purchases**, "Purchase", "Purchases", new {id = item.ClientId}). But this doesn't work because the first argument takes a string. I want to be able to click each item and it redirects to the page.

Comment: @Sfmar I've updated my answer, have a try now and let me know.

Comment: I tried this but got this error:  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Comment: @Sfmar this error will come up when `item.Purchases` is `null`, now what you can do is to make sure that value is asigned in `item.Purchases`, plus check whether the value is `null`, if `null` hide the link else display the link, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the question - is this what you are looking for?

*Note: I am assuming* `Purchases` *is a* `list`.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < item.Purchases.Count(); i++)
{
   @Html.ActionLink("link text", "action", "controller", new { id = item.ClientId }, null)
}
```

Comment: the purchases fields are shown in a table and I want to be able to select one of them and it should redirect me to another page. I would need something like this: @Html.ActionLink(**item.Purchases**, "Purchase", "Purchases", new {id = item.ClientId}) but this of course doesn't work because the first argument takes a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    @foreach(var purchase in  item.Purchases)
        {
   <td>
        @Html.ActionLink(purchase.Name, "Purchases", "Purchase", new {id = purchase.PurchaseId})
   </td>
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a jquery event on the tr click

First, its better to specify the data you want to send within the tr itself, like so:

```
<tr data-id="@item.ClientId"> [TDS] <tr>
```

And then you can have your jquery event somewhere else (In a .js file)

```
$('#TableId tbody').on('click','tr', function(e){
    var Id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    window.location.href = "/Purchase/Purchases/id=" + Id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna take a stab at this assuming these things: "Purchase" is the action and "Purchases" is the controller, and that what you want is clicking on any field will take you to the same page containing details about the item in that row (since you've included the ClientId in every example you've given).

What you need is to create an ActionLink for each of the displayed fields like so:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    string selectedRow = "success";
    if (item.ClientId == ViewBag.ClientId)
    {
        selectedRow = "success";
    }
    <tr class="@selectedRow">
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Purchase", "Purchases", new {id = item.ClientId }, null)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.Address, "Purchase", "Purchases", new {id = item.ClientId }, null)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.Number, "Purchase", "Purchases", new {id = item.ClientId }, null)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.Purchases, "Purchase", "Purchases", new {id = item.ClientId }, null)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

This overload of `@Html.ActionLink` requires a null value for htmlAttributes.
If your data is not of type string, like maybe item.Number, you can use `.ToString()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works as well but since Bilal gave a similar one first I had to consider his answer :) but thanks once again!